# Load date into Bootstrap Datetimepicker from View Model when loading a Form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to display a form which uses a ViewModel to load database values that have been passed by the controller.

Problem is, On loading the form I'm unable to load the Date fields in the `@Html.TextBoxFor` which points to the date field of the model. What am i doing wrong?? This happens only if I bind Bootstrap Datetimepicker with the TextBox but when I try loading it without Datetimepicker the date values shows up of course. Also I'm only concerned about the month so that's why setting `viewMode: 'months'` while initialising datetimepicker

Follwoing is how I'm doing it.

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public DateTime nextPmDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostAccountUDF", "Ticket", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "ReloadTable()" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
{
  <div class="item form-group">
    @Html.Label("Account Name :", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.accountName, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("PM Date :", new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" })
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group" id='pm_date'>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.nextPmDate, new { type = "text", name = "nextPmDate", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Init Datetimepicker 
    $('#pm_date').datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'months',
        format: 'MMM/YYYY'
    });
    // On show event, setting mode to show Months only
    $("#pm_date").on("dp.show", function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("DateTimePicker").viewMode("months");
    });
});
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: If you change the `on("dp.show")` to set data but without any viewMode, what happens?

Comment: No difference, still not loading.

Comment: When you don't use the datepicker, only an input text, how the datetime is displayed?

Comment: 01/02/2018 12:00:00 AM  
(i.e 1st of Feb)

Comment: Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.nextPmDate, "{0:MMM/yyyy}", new { ... })` so that the formats match. And as a side note, never set the `name` attribute (and its ignored anyway) and setting the `type` attribute is pointless also) - the `TextBoxFor()` already correctly sets those attributes

Comment: That worked like charm !! :)
So the idea was to make the component's format similar to what been set on datetimepicker.